# How to indent a specific line in a mini page

Tags: indentation, minipage

This is in a mini-page format:

I want to write the following but have all the lines that are started by $'s be indented by a set amount that I would like to play with until it looks right. I'd also like to be able to apply it to other situations so a generic form to be able to indent any line would be extremely useful.

I have tried using

```
\setlength{\parindent}{3cm}
\setlength{\parskip}{0cm}
```

The problem with this is that it still leaves a big gap between the line in between the lines.

Below is a portion of the text:

```
A chemist sell razor blades to her customers. She currently buys them in batches of $200$ every $2$ weeks at a cost of $£14$ per batch. The delivery cost is $20p$ per batch and the annual holding cost per unit is $26\%$ of the purchase price. Assuming instantaneous supply, constant demand and no shortages, should she alter her ordering policy? Furthermore, if the supplier offers a $5\%$ discount if she orders at least $500$ per batch, what is her optimal stock control policy?\\\\
This is the standard model with average cost per unit time\\
$ C =\frac{c_br_d}Q+c_pr_d+\frac{c_hQ}2$\\
is minimised for\\
$ Q^{*} =\sqrt{\frac{2c_br_d}{c_h}}$\\
We have\\
$ r_d =\frac{200}2=100$ razorblades per week\\
$ c_b =0.2$\\
$ c_p =\frac{£14}{200}=£0.07$ per razorblade\\
These give\\
$ Q^{*} = 339$\\
$ T^{*} = \frac{339}{100}=3.39$ weeks\\
$ C^{*} = £7.12$ per week\\
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an alternative suggestion that uses [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath)'s `[fleqn]`. It provides the length `\mathindent` which you can set to whatever you want:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[fleqn]{amsmath}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath
\setlength{\mathindent}{1cm}
\begin{document}
A chemist sell razor blades to her customers. She currently buys them in batches of~$200$ every~$2$ weeks at a cost of~$\pounds 14$ per batch. The delivery cost is~$20p$ per batch and the annual holding cost per unit is~$26\%$ of the purchase price. Assuming instantaneous supply, constant demand and no shortages, should she alter her ordering policy? Furthermore, if the supplier offers a~$5\%$ discount if she orders at least~$500$ per batch, what is her optimal stock control policy?

This is the standard model with average cost per unit time
\[ C =\frac{c_br_d}Q+c_pr_d+\frac{c_hQ}2 \]
is minimised for
\[ Q^{*} =\sqrt{\frac{2c_br_d}{c_h}} \]
We have
\begin{align*}
  r_d &= \frac{200}2=100 \text{ razorblades per week} \\
  c_b &= 0.2 \\
  c_p &=\frac{\pounds 14}{200} = \pounds 0.07 \text{ per razorblade}
\end{align*}
These give
\begin{align*}
  Q^{*} &= 339 \\
  T^{*} &= \frac{339}{100} = 3.39 \text{ weeks} \\
  C^{*} &= \pounds 7.12 \text{ per week}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

`\parindent` refers to the indent of the first line in a paragraph. In the above MWE, the `\parindent` is set to the default `20pt`. `\parskip` refers to the gap between paragraphs, of which you had none in your small code snippet. `\\` does not initiate a new paragraph.

Comment: It isn't ideal as it changes the settings for \begin{equation} but it did the trick in this instance. I'm constantly changing how I write my notes anyway so it won't be much work to adapt to this.

Comment: @DannyBland I don't see why using left aligned equations in some cases and centered in others.